# Java NegativeTest private method with Reflection to catch custom ApplicationException

Tags: java, testing, junit, reflection, private

So I'm testing a AccountService class with a mocked databaselayer.
In this AccountService class there is a private method that checks the input received from UI according to a regex.

The positive test I wrote is working fine:

```
@Test
public void testEmailPatroonCorrect() throws Exception{

    //Correcte emails
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    emails.add("user@domain.com");
    emails.add("user@domain.co.in");
    emails.add("user.name@domain.com");
    emails.add("user_name@domain.com");
    emails.add("username@yahoo.corporate.in");

    Class<AccountService> foo = AccountService.class;
    Method method = foo.getDeclaredMethod("checkEmailPatroon", String.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);

    assertThatCode(() -> {
        for(String email : emails){
            method.invoke(AccountService,email);
        }}).doesNotThrowAnyException();

}
```

However for the negative test (a list with wrong email patterns) even with only one object in the list for simplicity

```
@Test
public void testEmailPatroonFout() throws Exception{

    //Verkeerde emailpatronen
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    emails.add(".username@yahoo.com");

    Class<AccountService> foo = AccountService.class;
    Method method = foo.getDeclaredMethod("checkEmailPatroon", String.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);

    assertThatThrownBy(()->{
        for(String email : emails){
            method.invoke(AccountService,email);
        }
    }).isInstanceOf(ApplicationException.class).hasMessage(ApplicationExceptionType.ONGELDIGE_EMAIL.getMsg());

}
```

The exception thrown during test is: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. In the application the ApplicationException gets caught just fine. 
Question is how can I write a proper test for a list of wrong email patterns? (without using @VisibleForTesting functionality since it's a school project).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `InvocationTargetException` wraps the exception thrown within the reflectively invoked method. So you may catch the `InvocationTargetException` and rethrow its cause, but I’d put that into a utility method, like

```
public interface TestMethod<D,A> {
    void invoke(D d, A a) throws Throwable;
}
static <D,A> TestMethod<D,A> method(
    Class<D> declarer, String name, Class<A> argType) throws ReflectiveOperationException {

    Method method = declarer.getDeclaredMethod(name, argType);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    return (d,a) -> {
        try {
            method.invoke(d, a);
        } catch(InvocationTargetException ex) {
            throw ex.getTargetException();
        }
    };
}
```

which you can use like

```
@Test
public void testEmailPatroonFout() throws Exception{
    //Verkeerde emailpatronen
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    emails.add(".username@yahoo.com");

    TestMethod<AccountService, String> method
        = method(AccountService.class, "checkEmailPatroon", String.class);

    assertThatThrownBy(() -> {
        for(String email : emails){
            method.invoke(AccountService, email);
        }
    }).isInstanceOf(ApplicationException.class)
      .hasMessage(ApplicationExceptionType.ONGELDIGE_EMAIL.getMsg());
}
```

The shape of the `TestMethod` interface allows the alternative implementation like

```
static <D,A> TestMethod<D,A> method(
    Class<D> declarer, String name, Class<A> argType) throws ReflectiveOperationException {

    Method method = declarer.getDeclaredMethod(name, argType);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    return MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(
        TestMethod.class, MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(method));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Holger I was able to write a working test for it's purpose.

```
@Test
public void testEmailPatroonFoutLoop() throws Throwable {

    //Verkeerde emailpatronen
    List<String> wrongEmails = new ArrayList<>();
    wrongEmails.add(".username@yahoo.com");
    wrongEmails.add("username@yahoo.com.");
    wrongEmails.add("usernameyahoo.com");
    wrongEmails.add("username@yahoo.c");
    wrongEmails.add("use..rname@yahoo.com");

    Class<AccountService> foo = AccountService.class;
    Method method = foo.getDeclaredMethod("checkEmailPatroon", String.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);

    int countedWrongEmails = 0;
    for(String email : wrongEmails){
        try{
            method.invoke(accServ,email);
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException ie){
            Exception e = (Exception) ie.getTargetException();
            if(e.getMessage().equals(ApplicationExceptionType.ONGELDIGE_EMAIL.getMsg())){
                countedWrongEmails++;
            }
        }
    }
    assertThat(countedWrongEmails).isEqualTo(wrongEmails.size());
}
```

Although I see the benefits and elegance of writing a TestMethod interface, I however do not yet possess the knowledge to grasp it's complexity. So I will stick to this test that I'll be able to explain on the verbal exam.